# Intersite Login between 2 Custom Sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, web

We are creating a website which will be accessed though another website belonging to a third party.

The idea is the customer will login to the third party's website then at some later point be redirected to our own website without having to login a second time.

Ideally I'm looking for a simple solution which is also reasonably secure.

I'm toying with the idea of passing the user name and some sort of API key between the sites over the query string while using HTTPS, but I'm not sure if this a good idea or if there are better solutions.

Currently I am doing the following:

1. User login to website A
2. User clicks a button in website A
3. Website A (server side) sends the username over HTTPS to website B and an API key.
4. B gathers the user information and generates a new GUID/token. The data is stored in the server side cache against this token.
5. B Returns the token to A
6. A redirects the user to website B passing the token in the query string
7. B uses the token to login the user

Comment: Asking about [Single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)?

Comment: [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) FTW!

Comment: I think OAuth might be a bit overkill, this is probably more a case of secure communication between websites.
Also the sites may or may not be on the same domain so single sign on may not be possible

Comment: As long the api key stays hidden and is sent on server side, it shouldn't be a problem. What you are described is a bit what OAuth is doing. Look at the spec of OAuth. An added security would be for B to look at the IP of A.